# Android wear WearableListView ImageView selector

Tags: android, android-listview, wear-os

I am trying to create a list view as follows:-

[image]

Now, I have made the list view work successfully using the WearableListView adapter. However, I am using static images in the ImageView. What I want is to create this gray and blue kind of animation when a particular list element is focused while scrolling. How do I do that? I tried using a selector xml file for the ImageView but it seems this ListView doesnt make use of this selector(android:state-focused, selected, pressed-nothing works). Any idea how do I get what I want? Hope I made my question clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, image selector doesn't work, why? I don't know exactly and we don't have any documentation on it to read.

But fortunately I have implemented this scenario successfully and it's almost similar to the default settings screen.

For workaround, I have set circle color inside below methods:

1. `onScaleUpStart()` - Set circle color for selected item
2. `onScaleDownStart()` - Set circle color for non-selected items.

I have taken CircleImageView and TextView inside my item layout. Example code could be:

```
private final class MyItemView extends FrameLayout implements WearableListView.Item {

    final CircledImageView image;
    final TextView text;
    private float mScale;
    private final int mFadedCircleColor;
    private final int mChosenCircleColor;

    public MyItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.wearablelistview_item, this);
        image = (CircledImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mFadedCircleColor = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray);
        mChosenCircleColor = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
    }

    @Override
    public float getProximityMinValue() {
        return mDefaultCircleRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProximityMaxValue() {
        return mSelectedCircleRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public float getCurrentProximityValue() {
        return mScale;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScalingAnimatorValue(float value) {
        mScale = value;
        image.setCircleRadius(mScale);
        image.setCircleRadiusPressed(mScale);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleUpStart() {
        image.setAlpha(1f);
        text.setAlpha(1f);
        image.setCircleColor(mChosenCircleColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleDownStart() {
        image.setAlpha(0.5f);
        text.setAlpha(0.5f);
        image.setCircleColor(mFadedCircleColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: The WearableListView.Item is deprecated in the latest version. So, we cannot use those methods.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't know what has been lately as I haven't worked upon Wear module since a long! BTW, this answer was posted in 2014 :)

Answer (score 1):

New update brings **WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener** alternative of **WearableListView.Item** to implement Wearable list view with selector,

It has two methods to implement:

1. `onCenterPosition`
2. `onNonCenterPosition`

   ```
   public class WearableListItemLayout extends LinearLayout implements WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener {

   private CircledImageView image;
   private TextView text;

   public WearableListItemLayout(Context context) {
       this(context, null);
   }

   public WearableListItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       this(context, attrs, 0);
   }

   public WearableListItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onFinishInflate() {
       super.onFinishInflate();
       image = (CircledImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
       text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCenterPosition(boolean b) {
       image.setAlpha(1f);
       image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_oval);
       text.setAlpha(1f);
   }

   @Override
   public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean b) {
       image.setAlpha(0.5f);
       image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_oval);
       text.setAlpha(0.5f);
   }
   }
   ```