# Animating background image on circledimageview

Tags: android-view, wear-os

I'm referring to WatchFace sample for Android Wear. The example DigitialWatchFaceWearableConfigActivity uses a color picker to change the Watch Face background. I want to use an image background on the circledimageview. What happens is the image remains the same size in both center and non-centered positions and only the black circle changes size. What do I need to implement in onCenterPosition and onNonCenterPosition in order to shrink and grow the background image?

```
    @Override
    public void onCenterPosition(boolean animate) {

        if (animate) {
            mShrinkAnimator.cancel();
            if (!mExpandAnimator.isRunning()) {
                mExpandCircleAnimator.setFloatValues(mColor.getCircleRadius(), mExpandCircleRadius);
                mExpandLabelAnimator.setFloatValues(mLabel.getAlpha(), EXPAND_LABEL_ALPHA);
                mExpandAnimator.start();
            }
        } else {
            mExpandAnimator.cancel();
            mColor.setCircleRadius(mExpandCircleRadius);
            mLabel.setAlpha(EXPAND_LABEL_ALPHA);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean animate) {

        if (animate) {
            mExpandAnimator.cancel();
            if (!mShrinkAnimator.isRunning()) {
                mShrinkCircleAnimator.setFloatValues(mColor.getCircleRadius(), mShrinkCircleRadius);
                mShrinkLabelAnimator.setFloatValues(mLabel.getAlpha(), SHRINK_LABEL_ALPHA);
                mShrinkAnimator.start();
            }
        } else {
            mShrinkAnimator.cancel();
            mColor.setCircleRadius(mShrinkCircleRadius);
            mLabel.setAlpha(SHRINK_LABEL_ALPHA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can apply this code also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106866/android-wear-wearablelistview-imageview-selector/31206208#31206208

Answer (score 0):

You can use following simple code of ScaleX and ScaleY to manipulate background of onCenterPosition and onNonCenterPosition,

```
@Override
public void onCenterPosition(boolean b) {
    image.setAlpha(1f);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_oval); // This one is needed if you want to change background on center position
    image.setScaleX(1.0f);
    image.setScaleY(1.0f);
    text.setScaleY(1.0f);
    text.setAlpha(1f);

}

@Override
public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean b) {
    image.setAlpha(0.5f);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_oval); // This one is needed if you want to change background on non center position
    image.setScaleX(0.8f);
    image.setScaleY(0.8f);
    text.setScaleY(0.8f);

    text.setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```